# Export database with tables issue. Not keeping auto increment

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssms

I'm using SSMS to export some tables from a database on one server to a different database on a different server.

I'm using the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard to Export from the old one to the new one.
It works great but it does not keep the auto increment.

Is there a way to export with it keeping the auto increment **or is there a simple SQL code to tell all tables in the new database that the column "id" should be the primary key & auto inc?**

I can't export SQL scripts since they'll become too big.

Thank you.

Comment: have you tried backing up the db and restore it on the other server?

Comment: @apomene No I haven't. Mostly because the old one is filled with tons of tables and I don't want to export all of them.

Comment: Generate the Create scripts for the tables you want and then export the data to the new tables if you want the data too.  Right click on the database then Tasks => Generate Scripts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Database Scripting.

[image]

**Where to find Advance Scripting options**

[image]

**To select data when generating scripts**

[image]

Comment: Alright. Generating scripts to create the tables and then use the Export tool to transfer the data worked. Only had to force identity insert. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I create a sample table for this question

**DDL**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Brands](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL,

 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Merchants] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**DML**    SSMS create data scripts with Id fields For Ex.

```
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Brands] ON 

INSERT [dbo].[Brands] ([Id], [Name]) VALUES (1, N'Kitchenette')
INSERT [dbo].[Brands] ([Id], [Name]) VALUES (5, N'Mezzaluna')
INSERT [dbo].[Brands] ([Id], [Name]) VALUES (7, N'ESRA-MARKA')

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Brands] OFF
```

You need to change insert scripts like this

```
INSERT [dbo].[Brands] ([Name]) VALUES (N'Kitchenette')
INSERT [dbo].[Brands] ([Name]) VALUES (N'Mezzaluna')
INSERT [dbo].[Brands] ([Name]) VALUES (N'ESRA-MARKA')
```

So I delete Id in Insert. if you dont give Id , Auto Increament will work

Answer (score 1):

This is how I was able to successfully copy my MSSQL database preserving increment fields as well as preserving the identities of existing records.  I used MSSQL Server Studio 2016, but older versions of Studio should be similar. The process will work as an import to the destination database or export from the source database.  Right click on the database, then choose Tasks, then choose Import Data or Export Data depending which process you prefer.  On the first couple screens choose your source and destination databases.

On the next screen called "Source Tables and Views" screen, choose the tables you want to copy.  For each table that includes an increment field you must choose Edit Mappings.  On the Mappings screen, check "Enable identity insert".  Next, click the "Edit SQL" button.  Look for each increment field in the SQL statement.  Increment fields are type "int" and are "NOT NULL".  Insert sql statement "IDENTITY(1,1)" between the int variable type and "NOT NULL" specification.  The following is an example of an SQL statement that has an increment field called [ID]:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SomeTableName] (
[ID] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
...more sql here
)
```

Once all identity fields have been edited, run the import or export.